# Как перехватить исключение несоответствие типов ввода объекта cin?

Tags: c++

Читаем исходник. Нужно перехватить исключение несоответствие типов ввода

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int digit;
    cout << "enter a five digit: ";

    try{
        cin >> digit; 
    } catch (...){ // нужно перехватить исключение несоответствия типов ввода
        cout << "error" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    if (digit > 99999){
        cout << "error" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    char buf[6];

    _itoa_s(digit, buf, 10);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        cout << buf[i] << "_";
    }

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: catch(int) подойдет? std::terminate() тоже Вам в помощь.

Comment: @Вячеслав Кириченко нет не поймало ОС своё исключение выдает

Comment: Добавьте переменную x, тип string. Далее, string x; cin>>x; int digit=(int)x; - если нет, то тогда исключение будет перехвачено однозначно стандартным catch.

Comment: @Вячеслав Кириченко в задании четко написано, что нужно из cout записать в int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел на SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754486/test-cin-exception

```
int main(void)
{
    int n = 0;
    cin.exceptions(istream::failbit | istream::badbit);

    try
    {
        cin >> n;
    }
    catch(istream::failure e)
    {
        cerr << "Exception" << endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Зачем исключения использовать, если они сразу ловятся в той же функции? Вместо этого можно написать: `if (!(cin >> n)) cerr << "error\n";` без вызова `cin.exceptions()`.